# In Gradle 7, how to disable parallel compilation using command line option "-Porg.gradle.parallel=false"?

Tags: gradle-properties

In gradle document, `-Pxxx=yyy` commandline option is claimed to be able to override build property. So I want to override the property "org.gradle.parallel", which is already defined in the properties file and controls parallel execution.

When I run the following command:

```
$ ./gradlew test "-Porg.gradle.parallel=false"
```

The test execution is still parallel. How could this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct command is:

```
$ ./gradlew test "-Dorg.gradle.parallel=false"
```

And apparently `-P` won't apply to built-in properties